# How to give permissions in dovecot to receive mails?

Tags: permissions, email, postfix, mail, dovecot

I'm installed iredmail on new server. I'm able to send emails but I'm not able to receive mails.
I've checked the logs and tried to change the permissions and the group permissions but nothing works.

This error comes in the mail.log.

```
Error reading configuration: stat(/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf) failed: Permission denied (euid=2000(vmail) egid=2000(vmail) missing +x perm: /etc/dovecot, we're not in group 118(dovecot), dir owned by 8:118 mode=0750) lda: Fatal: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. )
```

I'm not able to solve this. How can I give permissions to dovecot user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message explicitly tells you that the **/etc/dovecot** directory needs the +x permission, so that should have been the first thing you tried.

```
chmod +x /etc/dovecot
```